# How do I detect what guild a user joins in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I use this code here to detect when a user joins and send a message, but I want it to only send a message when it joins the guild "Bongo's Diner":

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member =>{

    const welcomeChannel = client.channels.cache.get('713215120305815612');
    welcomeChannel.send(`Welcome to the server, <@${member.id}>. I hope you enjoy your stay here at Bongo's Diner.

Be sure to check out <#713227378306056244> to grab a color and learn how to get ping roles. If you have a question, check out <#713194923909972159>.`);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using `guildMemberAdd` and have access to a `member` instance, just call `member.guild`:

```js
const guild = member.guild;
console.log(guild);
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember